# Placing MySQL connector JAR in WEB-INF/lib of my WAR instead of in tomcat lib making j_security_check fail

Tags: mysql, tomcat6, connector, context.xml

I want my webapp to use the MySQL connector JAR present in web-inf/lib . But j-security_check dosen't work when i do it. When I place the jar in tomcat lib folder it works fine. But I have purchased a shared tomcat hosting and they wouldn't let me put a jar in tomcat lib.
Is it possible to use j_security_check and connection pool without the jar in tomcat lib.

Following is my META-INF/context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="600" maxIdle="30" maxWait="20000" removeAbandoned="true" logAbandoned="false"
          username="usr_1" password="password1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/daname?autoReconnect=true"/>


<Realm name="myRealm" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" debug="99"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/myDB" localDataSource="true"
       userTable="user" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="pass"
       userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can, for example it is possible to configure Hibernate to create and manage its own connection pool, but if you want the container to manage resources (including database connections) then it needs to be able to see the class and hence needs the classes in the common folder and not attached to a single web application

Comment: in your case, create a session context listener and when the application starts, you can initialise and bind your connection pool to JNDI.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is resolved , but I still am not sure how. When I upload a war on the running tomcat webapps directory , it works fine (dosen't require the jar in its lib) , but when i put the files(in webapps) and started tomcat , it failed(worked on placing the jar in tomcat lib) . So, not even sure if the problem was of the jar in the first place.